Merge effectively mono content recorded in stereo for best quality
I captured stereo audio from a cassette tape that was probably recorded from a mono source. Because of the quality of the tape or condition of the heads, could one channel have better quality than the other? Could it go back and forth as the tape plays? Is there a way to automatically gauge each channel's quality? Am I better off choosing one channel, mixing the two to mono, leaving them as stereo, or is there an automated tool for alternating between channels depending on which is higher quality?


Could one channel have better quality than the other?

Yes. Most analog stereo use sum/difference encoding at the physical layer but for some reason cassette tape uses straight left/right encoding. Tape is relatively "fragile" so the quality of the sound can vary a fair bit along the tape (both in time and channel).

Could it go back and forth as the tape plays?

Yes.

Am I better off choosing one channel, mixing the two to mono, leaving them as stereo, or is there an automated tool for alternating between channels depending on which is higher quality?

The best way would be to chop up the audio in frames, calculate a "quality metric", Q, for each frame calculate over and downmix the two channels in each frame using something like
$$y(t) = Q(t)\cdot x_{left}(t) + (1-Q(t)) \cdot x_{right}(t) $$
If both channels have the same quality, you want to sum them with equal weights: this reduces uncorrelated noise. If one channel is "better", you want  take more of the better one. Note, that this is "constant amplitude" fade, not a "constant energy" fade. That's because your channels are likely to be highly correlated.
There are various ways a quality metric could be constructed. Typical tape problems are high frequency loss, wow or flutter, "gurgling" noises, excessive noise, etc.
Almost all stereo recordings are "well balanced", i.e. the average power spectral density is the same on both channels. That's even more the case if you have a "mono source". You can look for difference in mean, RMS, spectral extension (specifically at higher frequencies). You can also look at "spectral stability" i.e. the spectral width of narrow band components (narrower is better).
A good start would be to take a few representative recordings and take a listen what type of artifacts you have and how different they are between the channels. It's typically more efficient to focus on problems that you are actually having.
